# WP_Query - Display Custom Posts In Specific Category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to run a query that returns my custom posts from a single category. I've tried by category ID (`'cat'=> 83`,) and category slug (`'category_name => 'slugname'`,) but both return an empty result.

```
$custom_args = array(

'post_type' => 'event',
'cat'    => 83,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_key' => 'event_date', // name of custom field
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args );
```

Comment: is your custom post type registered to use the built in categories or is it a custom taxonomy that it's using?

Comment: Hi. It's a custom taxonomy I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom taxonomy then you need to modify your query as like below :

```
$custom_args = array(

'post_type' => 'event',
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
            'terms' => 'bob' //if field is ID you can reference by cat/term number
        )
    )
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_key' => 'event_date', // name of custom field
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args );
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to place that code in and it breaks the page (white page of death). I can't see where it's failing :/

Comment: Have you defined the name of your  **custom taxonomy**  here => `'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
            'terms' => 'bob' //if field is ID you can reference by cat/term number
        )
    )`

Comment: Yes, I lifted the whole array and put it in place of my query.  Thanks for the help so far, btw!

Answer (score 0):

He miss a "," here the good code :

```
$custom_args = array(

'post_type' => 'event',
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
            'terms' => 'bob' //if field is ID you can reference by cat/term number
        )
    ),
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_key' => 'event_date', // name of custom field
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args );
```